# How to Reuse BaseAdapter view for multiple lists

Tags: java, android

I have a `BaseAdapter` list view that takes a `List<objects>` and I would like to reuse it with different lists. How do I go about this?

Comment: Make your ListView (Different One) and Set adapter for it. I guess ?

Comment: your question is too vague, it is unclear what your problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new instance for each ListView you need.

For example, suppose you have a BaseAdapter called MyAdapter and two ListViews.

```
MyAdapter myFirstAdapter = new MyAdapter(objects);
myFirstListView.setAdapter(myFirstAdapter);

MyAdapter mySecondAdapter = new MyAdapter(objects);
mySecondListView.setAdapter(mySecondAdapter);
```

You should not use the same adapter instance for different ListView, but you can use the same class with distinct instance.

Answer (score 3):

Use Java Generics. Create MyBaseAdapter using generics. And then, when you will need the same adapter behavior but with different objects (student, worker, child) you will need to change only object name in when you ceate new adapter instance.

```
new MyBaseAdapter<Student>();
new MyBaseAdapter<Worker>();
```